# [Blazor]Data binding is invalid when property values are modified inside an object

Tags: razor, data-binding, blazor

I bind the name of Student to the input Tag.

If i change the value in the input tag, the data bind is OK, but when i use the "start" button to invoke student.start() to change the name, it not work as expected, the value of input not change.

Did I do something wrong?

razor component:

```
@page "/data-bind"

@using blazor_winform_sample.Entity;

<h3>data bind test</h3>

<div>
    <div>
        <button @onclick="Start">go!</button>
        <label>@toast</label>
    </div>

    <input type="text" readonly @bind="Stu.Name" />

    <input type="text" @bind="@Stu.Name" />
    <input type="text" value="@Stu.Name" @onchange="@changeValue" />
</div>

@code {
    private Student Stu{ get; set; } = new();

    void changeValue(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        Stu.Name = "haha" + e?.Value?.ToString();
    }
    private string getName()
    {
        return Stu.Name;
    }

    private string toast = "";
    private void Start()
    {
        Stu.start();
        toast = "start button clicked!";
    }
}
```

class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace blazor_winform_sample.Entity
{
    public class Student
    {
        private string _name = "";
        public string Name { get { return _name; } set { _name = value; } }

        public Student() { }

        public void start()
        {
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    _name = new Random().Next() + "";
                    Thread.Sleep(500);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I tried use INotifyPropertyChanged to notify, but it not works.

Answer (score 2):

Apologies but :

```cs
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    _name = new Random().Next() + "";
                    Thread.Sleep(500);
                }
            });
```

is not nice code!  It blocks the thread: in WASM it will block the application.

You need to implement a timer and an event like this:

```cs
using System.Timers;

public class Student : IDisposable
{
    private System.Timers.Timer aTimer;
    private string _name = "";
    public event EventHandler? NameUpdated;
    public string Name { get { return _name; } set { _name = value; } }

    public Student()
    {
        aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
        // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer. 
        aTimer.Elapsed += this.OnTimedEvent;
    }

    public void start()
    {
        aTimer.AutoReset = true;
        aTimer.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void OnTimedEvent(Object? source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        _name = new Random().Next() + "";
        this.NameUpdated?.Invoke(null, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        aTimer.Elapsed -= this.OnTimedEvent;
        aTimer.Dispose();
    }
}
```

And then your page looks like this.

1. Hooks up a listener to the event to update the UI when the change event occurs.
2. Implements IDisposable to clean up resources when the component is itself disposed by the Renderer.

```cs
@implements IDisposable

@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h3>data bind test</h3>

<div>
    <div>
        <button @onclick="Start">go!</button>
        <label>@toast</label>
    </div>

    <input type="text" readonly @bind="Stu.Name" />

    <input type="text" @bind="@Stu.Name" />
    <input type="text" value="@Stu.Name" @onchange="@changeValue" />
</div>

@code {
    private Student Stu { get; set; } = new();

    protected override void OnInitialized()
        => Stu.NameUpdated += OnNameUpdated;

    void changeValue(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        Stu.Name = "haha" + e?.Value?.ToString();
    }

    private string getName()
    {
        return Stu.Name;
    }

    private string toast = "";

    private void Start()
    {
        Stu.start();
    }

    private void OnNameUpdated(object? sender, EventArgs e)
        => this.InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Stu.NameUpdated -= OnNameUpdated;
        Stu.Dispose();
        }

}
```

Comment: Ah, thank you, sir! I'm a newbie to dotnet, I still have a lot to learn! the key is "InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged)", i got it! Of course "Dispose" is important for safe too.

Comment: NP.  The technique is known as the Notification Pattern, and in this case you need to invoke `StateHasChanged` on the UI thread as the timer may well be running on a separate thread.

Comment: You should also mark the question as answered if this answer answers your question.  It stops others thinking it still needs an answer, and answerer's reading it all to discover it's answered.